# How to move one field out of a struct that implements Drop trait?

Tags: rust

Here's an invalid Rust program (Rust version 1.1) with a function that does an HTTP client request and returns only the headers, dropping all other fields in the response.

```
extern crate hyper;

fn just_the_headers() -> Result<hyper::header::Headers, hyper::error::Error> {
    let c = hyper::client::Client::new();
    let result = c.get("http://www.example.com").send();
    match result {
        Err(e) => Err(e),
        Ok(response) => Ok(response.headers),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", just_the_headers());
}
```

Here are the compiler errors:

```
main.rs:8:28: 8:44 error: cannot move out of type `hyper::client::response::Response`, which defines the `Drop` trait
main.rs:8         Ok(response) => Ok(response.headers),
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I understand *why* the borrow checker doesn't accept this program—i.e., that the `drop` function will use the `response` after it has had its `headers` member moved.

My question is: How can I get around this and still have good safe Rust code? I know I can do a *copy*, via `clone()`, like so:

```
Ok(response) => Ok(response.headers.clone()),
```

But, coming from C++, that seems inefficient. Why *copy* when a *move* should suffice? I envision in C++ doing something like the following to force a call to a move constructor, if available:

```
headers_to_return = std::move(response.headers);
```

Is there any way to forgo the *copy* in Rust and instead force a *move*, similar to C++?

Comment: This won't technically move the member value, but if you're OK to change your structure a bit, but you can wrap the headers by changing the type of `response.headers` to `Option<Headers>` and `take()` its value. This will reset the value to None, which is useful if you're unable to find a good default value for your type (e.g. a `thread`).
This is done in https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [`std::mem::replace()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to swap the field with a new blank value in order to transfer ownership to you:

```
extern crate hyper;

fn just_the_headers() -> Result<hyper::header::Headers, hyper::error::Error> {
    let c = hyper::client::Client::new();
    let result = c.get("http://www.example.com").send();
    match result {
        Err(e) => Err(e),
        Ok(mut response) => Ok(std::mem::replace(&mut response.headers, hyper::header::Headers::new())),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", just_the_headers());
}
```

Here, we're replacing `response.headers` with a new empty set of headers. `replace()` returns the value that was stored in the field before we replaced it.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that `std::mem::replace` in Rust is *more or less* what `std::move` is in C++.  Because the source and destination must be valid to destruct both before *and after* a move, C++ doesn't really move, it swaps.

Comment: Indeed, with the difference that in C++, it is the class that decides how to implement the move (in the move constructor or move assignment operator), whereas `std::mem::replace` requires the caller to provide a suitable value. In fact, `std::mem::replace` is implemented in terms of [`std::mem::swap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

Comment: You might wish to note that Rust also places on emphasis on extremely efficient "default constructs", for example neither `String::new()` nor `Vec::new()` allocate memory, which is what makes this replace as efficient as the C++ move on top of being safer.

Comment: @FrancisGagné and to finish that thought, Rust types don't define how they swap either, their byte representations are simply swapped.

Comment: Thanks! Is using `std::mem::replace` for this use case idiomatic? (Is what I'm trying to do — to force a _move_ instead of a _copy_ — idiomatic?) I ask because the call to `std::mem::replace` seems like a lot of typing to do something that could be a common use case.

Comment: `std::mem::replace` seems to be the most suitable tool to use to take ownership of a value you can't take ownership of with Rust's standard ownership rules. Don't forget you can use `use` declarations to make names shorter, e.g. `use std::mem;`, then `mem::replace`, or `use std::mem::replace`, then `replace`. The preferred style is to use functions qualified on the module (`mem::replace`), but types unqualified (`Headers`).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the `hyper` crate now has a different API which supports taking the headers by value. Here is the solution for hyper 14.2 (Rust edition 2021, version 1.69):

```
extern crate http;
extern crate hyper;

async fn just_the_headers() -> Result<http::header::HeaderMap, hyper::Error> {
    let c = hyper::client::Client::new();
    let result = c
        .get(hyper::Uri::from_static("http://www.example.com"))
        .await;
    match result {
        Err(e) => Err(e),
        Ok(response) => Ok(response.into_parts().0.headers),
    }
}
```

A lot has changed since Rust 1.1. async/await is now a first-class part of the language (stabilized in Rust 1.39). We also have the new `?` operator, stabilized in Rust 1.13. Using this operator, the code becomes

```
extern crate http;
extern crate hyper;

async fn just_the_headers() -> Result<http::header::HeaderMap, hyper::Error> {
    Ok(hyper::client::Client::new()
        .get(hyper::Uri::from_static("http://www.example.com"))
        .await?
        .into_parts()
        .0
        .headers)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Rust 1.40.0 (released in December 2019), `std::mem::take` should be used. [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html) mention:

```rust
pub fn take<T>(dest: &mut T) -> T
where
    T: Default,


Replaces dest with the default value of T, returning the previous dest value.
```

This is how it will be used in your example:

```
fn just_the_headers() -> Result<hyper::header::Headers, hyper::error::Error> {
    let c = hyper::client::Client::new();
    let result = c.get("http://www.example.com").send();
    match result {
        Err(e) => Err(e),
        Ok(response) => Ok(std::mem::take(&mut response.headers)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", just_the_headers());
}
```