# How can I move a value out of the argument to Drop::drop()?

Tags: rust

I'm using `gfx-hal`, which requires me to create resources which need to be explicitly destroyed using functions specific to their type. I'd like to store instances of these types in structs, and I'd also like to tie cleaning them up to the lifetime of the owning struct, instead of managing their lifetimes manually and potentially having objects on the GPU/in the driver live forever.

However, all the functions in the `destroy` family of functions take the type directly, rather than a reference, so when I try to pass them from my structs, I get errors like the following:

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `S`, which implements the `Drop` trait
 --> src/lib.rs:9:18
  |
9 |         destroyT(self.member)
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of here
```

It seems like there should be some way around this issue, as I'm currently in the `Drop::drop` function itself, so `self` is already "consumed." How do I get the instances of these types out of `self` as `T`, and not `&T`?

```
struct T;

struct S {
    member: T,
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroyT(self.member)
    }
}

// elsewhere, in a library

fn destroyT(t: T) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one to find this frustrating: https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/issues/2452

Comment: Couldn't you use a NewType for `T` that implements `Drop` and calls `destroy()`. That way, the `Drop` for `S` would be automatically generated.

Comment: @rodrigo Isn't that exactly what the OP was trying to do?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oh, I see. I was assuming `S` was some composite type. But then the NewType would be exactly like this `S`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **safest**, easiest way to do this is to use an `Option`:

```rust
struct T;

impl Drop for T {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping T");
    }
}

struct S {
    member: Option<T>,
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(t) = self.member.take() {
            destroy_t(t);
        }
    }
}

fn destroy_t(_t: T) {
    println!("destroy T");
}

fn main() {
    let _x = S { member: Some(T) };
}
```

---

You could choose to use unsafe code with [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) and [swap out the current value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423) for an uninitialized one:

```rust
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

struct T;

impl Drop for T {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping T");
    }
}

struct S {
    member: MaybeUninit<T>,
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let invalid_t = MaybeUninit::uninit();
        let valid_t = mem::replace(&mut self.member, invalid_t);
        let valid_t = unsafe { valid_t.assume_init() };
        destroy_t(valid_t);
        // Dropping MaybeUninit does nothing
    }
}

fn destroy_t(_t: T) {
    println!("destroy T");
}

fn main() {
    let _x = S {
        member: MaybeUninit::new(T),
    };
}
```

See also:

- [How to move one field out of a struct that implements Drop trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31307680/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm trying to get my head around this, but the call for `assume_init()` does re-activates the drop on `T` right? In which case, `valid_t` still gets dropped at the end of `S::drop()`, I think?
Maybe using `assume_init_mut()` prevents the drop from happening?

Comment: @ThiagoMachado yes, `MaybeUninit<T>::assume_init` gives back a `T` which is then subject to normal drop rules. *`valid_t` still gets dropped at the end of `S::drop()`* — it does not, as ownership of the `T` is transferred to `destroy_t`. `T` itself doesn't actually implement a `Drop` that does anything interesting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ManuallyDrop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html#method.take). It has no overhead and a clear API. It is less of a pain to use than `MaybeUninit` since it doesn't require `unsafe` to use elsewhere (access to the inner value is available by simple `Deref`) and it only requires `unsafe` to actually move the value out.

```
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

struct T;

impl Drop for T {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping T");
    }
}

struct S {
    member: ManuallyDrop<T>,
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // SAFETY: this is safe because we do not access `self.member` any more
        let member = unsafe { ManuallyDrop::take(&mut self.member) };
        destroy_t(member);
        
        // dropping a `ManuallyDrop` does nothing
    }
}

fn destroy_t(_t: T) {
    println!("destroy T");
}

fn main() {
    let _x = S {
        member: ManuallyDrop::new(T),
    };
}
```

```
destroy T
dropping T
```

Keep in mind, as evidenced by the name, `ManuallyDrop` will prevent the inner value from being dropped unless `ManuallyDrop::take` or `ManuallyDrop::into_inner` is called (thereby removing it from protections and normal drop rules will apply) or if `ManuallyDrop::drop` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [consume_on_drop](https://docs.rs/consume_on_drop/0.1.1/consume_on_drop/) crate to do this. Full disclosure: I am the author of this crate.

```rust
extern crate consume_on_drop;
use consume_on_drop::{Consume, ConsumeOnDrop};
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

// We have a library given to us.
mod library_code {
    pub struct T;
    pub fn destroyT(_t: T) {
        // code ommitted
    }
    impl T {
        pub fn borrow_t(&self) {
            // code ommitted
        }
        pub fn borrow_mut_t(&mut self) {
            // code ommitted
        }
    }
}

use library_code::T;

// We can't implement consume for T itself, since T is defined
// in a library. We need a wrapper that implements Consume.
struct TConsume(T);

// The Consume trait defines what happens to our TConsume when
// we drop a value of type ConsumeOnDrop<TConsume>.
impl Consume for TConsume {
    fn consume(self) {
        library_code::destroyT(self.0)
    }
}

// Dropping S will call destroyT on the underlying T.
// S is a zero-overhead wrapper around T.
pub struct S(ConsumeOnDrop<TConsume>);

impl Deref for S {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0.0
    }
    // We can now call s.borrow_t() where s: S
}

impl DerefMut for S {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.0.0
    }
    // We can now call s.borrow_mut_t() where s: S
}

impl S {
    /// Turn our S back into the underlying T
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        ConsumeOnDrop::into_inner(self.0).0
    }

    /// Turn a T into an S
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Self(ConsumeOnDrop::new(TConsume(val)))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S::new(T);
    s.borrow_t();
    s.borrow_mut_t();
    drop(s); // Calls destroyT on underlying T
}
```

Alternately, if you don't care about giving the type `S` a name, you can use `WithConsumer`. In the code below, `s` is a zero-overhead wrapper around `T` which, when dropped, will have the consumer `library_code::destroyT` called on its underlying `T`.

You can also use a closure as a consumer, though closures may take up a nonzero amount of space (unlike a statically known function item like `library_code::destroyT`). This approach has the benefit of brevity, but you cannot actually name the type of `s`. It's possible that in the future, support for `impl Trait` will improve to the point that we can always use `WithConsumer` over `ConsumeOnDrop`.

```rust
extern crate consume_on_drop;
use consume_on_drop::WithConsumer;

mod library_code {
   ... // same library code as above
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = WithConsumer::new(T, library_code::destroyT);
    s.borrow_t();
    s.borrow_mut_t();
    drop(s); // calls destroyT on the underlying T
}
```